# Questions related to splunk builtin macros in correlation search

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I am not sure if this is the appropriate forum to ask this question, but really need help and I am stuck. So here goes : I am exploring splunk enterprise security and was specifically looking into analytic stories and correlation searches.
For example :
Analytic story : Trickbot

Correlation search : Attempt to stop security service

```
| tstats `security_content_summariesonly` values(Processes.process) as process min(_time) as firstTime max(_time) as lastTime from datamodel=Endpoint.Processes where (Processes.process_name = net.exe OR  Processes.process_name = sc.exe) Processes.process="* stop *" by Processes.dest Processes.user Processes.parent_process Processes.process_name Processes.process Processes.process_id Processes.parent_process_id 
| `drop_dm_object_name(Processes)` 
| `security_content_ctime(firstTime)` 
| `security_content_ctime(lastTime)` 
|lookup security_services_lookup service as process OUTPUTNEW category, description 
| search category=security 
| `attempt_to_stop_security_service_filter`
```

I am trying to understand what exactly this code is doing, but stuck at these macros like `security_content_summariesonly, drop_dm_object_name, security_content_ctime, attempt_to_stop_security_service_filter`. I can't find definitions for these macros anywhere. I have tried to look into -> settings -> advance search -> macros, but these are not listed there.

Can somebody help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to the host(s) Splunk's running on, you can find the [definitions](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Admin/Macrosconf) in `$SPLUNK_HOME$/etc/*/macros.conf`

If you *don't* have that access, then it's possible you don't have permissions to see the definitions of those macros

However, you can always use the [Job Inspector](https://docs.splunk.com/Splexicon:Searchjobinspector) to see how Splunk translates what you type into what it runs

Answer (score 0):

If you have the query in a search window then click on the query and type Shift-CTRL-E to have Splunk expand all of the macros for you.

I can tell you the `drop_dm_object_name` macro is just `rename $1.* as *`.  The other macros are specific to their app.

Answer (score 0):

now the macros are opened source and managed in Github. For example `security_content_summariesonly` is defined [here](https://github.com/splunk/security_content/blob/develop/macros/security_content_summariesonly.yml), likewise [security_content_ctime](https://github.com/splunk/security_content/blob/develop/macros/security_content_ctime.yml)